# How do I add this data to Firebase?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, nosql

[image]

This is how i structured my database and I want to add the node from burger (as given by user) I have used this:

`mDatabase.child(rid).child(Category).child("name"+i).setValue(itemClass);`
to achieve this, where:

category ~ burger

name ~ name0

itemClass is a class having two fields: name and price.

But as expected this doesn't work. Why and how can we achieve this?

I have a activity from which the user can add the category of food along with the food items associated with the category(eg burger) . I basically want to append the category node to the restaurant id(given by rid)

```
public void updateToDatabase() {
    ItemClass itemClass = new ItemClass();
    String Price;
    String Category = category_name.getText().toString();
    String rid,name,price;
    EditText et_Name;
    EditText et_Price;

    //Initialize
    SharedPreferences preferences = getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences("Restaurant_Pref",0);
    rid = preferences.getString("rid",null);
    mDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Menu");


    for (int i=0; i <= linearLayout.getChildCount()-1;i++) {
        Log.d("DB", "updateToDatabase: "+ linearLayout.getChildAt(i).toString());
        View view_CardLayout = linearLayout.getChildAt(i);
        if (view_CardLayout instanceof CardView) {
            Log.d("DB", "updateToDatabase: " + ((CardView) view_CardLayout).getChildCount());
            Log.d("DB", "updateToDatabase: " + ((CardView) view_CardLayout).getChildAt(0));

            View view_LinearLayout = ((CardView) view_CardLayout).getChildAt(0);
            if (view_LinearLayout instanceof LinearLayout) {
                Log.d("DB", "updateToDatabase: " + ((LinearLayout) view_LinearLayout).getChildCount());
                Log.d("DB", "updateToDatabase: " + ((LinearLayout) view_LinearLayout).getChildAt(0));

                View et_name = ((LinearLayout) view_LinearLayout).getChildAt(0);
                View et_price = ((LinearLayout) view_LinearLayout).getChildAt(1);

                if (et_name instanceof EditText) {

                    et_Name = ((EditText) et_name);
                    name = et_Name.getText().toString();
                    itemClass.setName(name);
                    Log.d("Logs:", "updateToDatabase: " + et_Name.getText().toString());
                }
                if (et_price instanceof EditText) {
                   et_Price = ((EditText) et_price);
                    price = et_Price.getText().toString();
                    itemClass.setPrice(Integer.parseInt(price));
                    Log.d("Logs:", "updateToDatabase: " + et_Price.getText().toString());
                }
            }
        }
        mDatabase.child(rid).child(Category).child("name"+i).child("name").setValue(itemClass.getName());
        mDatabase.child(rid).child(Category).child("name"+i).child("price").setValue(itemClass.getPrice());
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you clarify what is not working? it's being replaced? it's raising an exception? if yes you should paste the log error

Comment: Hi, it is neither raising errors nor updating the values. Is this the right way?

Comment: what really you wanna achieve ?

Comment: Hi I have a activity from which the user can add the category of food along with the food items associated with the category(eg burger) . I basically want to append the category node to the restaurant id(given by rid)

Comment: So basically nothing happened? I think you might want to paste your code here, so we can figure out what's happening

Comment: @Shermano yes i guess so ;)

Comment: Are you sure that "rid" isn't null? i mean you debugged you app alredy to see it these variables (rid, Category) are ok?. PS: you can add your object on setvalue instead of adding each attribute

Comment: Yes I checked, they are all good.

Comment: What is the value of linearLayout.getChildCount()?

Comment: It depends on the number of item the user has choosed to put in the category.

Comment: Maybe there is problem with the name. Try String name = "name"+i;  mDatabase.child(rid).child(Category).child(name).child("name").setValue(itemClass.getName());

Comment: Hey Thank you for your suggestions. Got it, I don't know why, but the same code seems to work now. Thank you all for your time :)

Comment: "How do I add this data to Firebase?" Isn't already added?